# error CS0246 from Jenkins MSbuild but compiles fine from VS

Tags: jenkins, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have just installed `Jenkins 19.2`, and I am using `MSBuild` to build my solution.

I have successfully integrated Jenkins with my `TFS`, and I have downloaded my solution to the Jenkins workspace.

My local solution compiles and builds fine from `VS2015`. But I am getting 157 errors after trying to build the solution that was downloaded from Jenkins (Jenkins Workspace).

All the errors are of the following type:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name '' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have also tried running MSBuild from command prompt (`c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`) against **my local solution's startup project** and it builds fine with no errors. This is the local solution that builds find from VS2015.

But when I try running MSBuild (again `c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`) against the **solution's startup project downloaded from Jenkins** (Jenkins Workspace), I get the 157 errors again.

Comment: Having a similar problem with Visual Studio Team Services. Builds fine using my local machine or even the hosted VSTS build agent. Using a local build agent, I get the CS0246 errors. Leads me to believe there's something not installed/configured properly on our local agent, but no idea what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2015 uses MSBuild version 14.0, not the old version from the path you specified. The right one should be on your `PATH` (at `c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`) when you're inside a "Developer Command Prompt for VS2015". When you use the newer MSBuild, do you still see the error?

Jenkins appears to have the ability to specify an MSBuild location, so if you can fix this locally by using the newer MSBuild, you should be able to configure Jenkins to invoke the new MSBuild.

While MSBuild 4.0 is part of the .NET Framework and almost always available on Windows, MSBuild 12.0 and newer are Visual Studio components. You may have to install the "Microsoft Build Tools 2015" package from [the Visual Studio site](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#).

Comment: I used c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release;TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.5.1;ToolsVersion=4.0 /t:rebuild, but I still get the same errors.

Comment: Why are you specifying the target framework and tools version on the command line? If you open a Visual Studio command prompt and just do msbuild <solution>, does that work?

Comment: When I use MSBuild against my local solution, it builds with no errors. But when I use MSBuild against the solution downloaded from Jenkins (which should be the same solution as the one I am working on locally), I get all those errors.

Comment: Any solution on this one, I'm having the same issue here?

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped setting `/p:VisualStudioVersion` property in MSBuild (ex, `/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0`).

As [Team Services MSBuild Q&A](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/msbuild#qa) says:

> #### Should I use the Visual Studio Build step or the MSBuild step?
>
> If you are building a solution, in most cases you should use the Visual Studio Build step. This step automatically:
>
> - Sets the `/p:VisualStudioVersion` property for you. This forces MSBuild to use a particular set of targets that increase the likelihood of a successful build.
> - Specifies the MSBuild version argument.